# How to remove html redirection in devise authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rabl

I use the devise's authenticate_user! method in a controller. This is working fine when the auth_token provided in the request is the correct one but if the authentication fails, I end up with:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:3000/my_obj?auth_token=wrongtoken'

<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

As I use rabl, what is the best way to have something like

```
{'error' : 'authentication error'}
```

returned intead of the html redirection ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I do that in avoid the filter with :format => :json response and do my own filter to render my  JSON response if no current_user pass

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :unless => { request.format == :json }
  before_filter :user_needed, :if => { request.format == :json }

  def user_needed
    unless current_user
      render :json => {'error' => 'authentication error'}, :status => 401
    end
  end
end
```

An other way, can be cleaner is to define your own FailureApp ( https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/failure_app.rb )

```
class MyFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    if request.format == :json
      json_failure
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def json_failure
    self.status = 401
    self.content_type = 'application/json'
    self.response_body = "{'error' : 'authentication error'}"
  end
end
```

In your Devise config file add :

```
config.warden do |manager| 
  manager.failure_app = MyFailureApp 
end
```

Comment: I tried the second approach to avoid having to repeat the same code in all my controllers. I created the class MyFailureApp into lib/failure.rb and change the configuration. I do not manage to have it working though, I get the '!! Unexpected error while processing request: uninitialized constant MyFailureApp'. Any idea why this guy does not get loaded ?

Comment: You need require your file require 'failure' in your top of Devise configuration

Comment: happy it's work to you. I need using this cleanest way in my project too, lol

Comment: @shingara `== :json` is missing in `if request.format == :json`(`respond` method), isn't it?. Otherwise, the `json_failure` would be rendered in other formats such HTML as well.

Comment: This solution works great! However, when I tested the response body, I kept getting `JSON::ParserError` exceptions so I ended up setting the `response_body` as `{error: 'Authentication error'}.to_json`. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 38):

In newer versions of Devise (I'm using 2.2.0), you can use the `navigational_formats` option in the Devise config file, `devise.rb`:

```
# ==> Navigation configuration
# Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
# :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
# access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
#
# If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
# should add them to the navigational formats lists.
#
# The "*/*" below is required to match Internet Explorer requests.
config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html]
```

So long as `:json` is not in that list, and your request ends in `.json`, it will behave as you want.

Comment: This saved me an incredible amount of time, thank you!

Comment: I was baffled all day until I saw your point about the request ending in .json. Good show, good show.

Comment: Add `application/json` to `Headers` of the request and you don't need `.json` at the end f the url.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, term navigational is quite confusing and makes this comment easy to skip in devise config.