# Rails, Ruby Not Showing Status Unauthorized - Syntax Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rabl

When trying to request JSON from a resource not owned by a User, despite the validation I wrote below, the JSON shows up as empty brackets, but the status comes back as 200 OK.  What do I need to change to respond with a 401 status:

```
    @requested_resource = params[:resource_id].to_i
    @users_resources = Resource.owned_by(@current_user.id).collect {|s| s.id}
    if @users_resources.include?(@requested_resource)

    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => [], :status => :unauthorized }
        format.html { render :file => "public/401.html", :status => :unauthorized }
      end
    end
```

Also, I am using RABL...

Answer (score 1):

Let RoR play the game for you, use [`redirect_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) instead of `respond_to`. E.g.:

```
redirect_to "public/401.html", :alert => "Please authorize", :status => :unauthorized
```

Comment: Switching to redirect_to results in a 304 Not Modified Status.

Comment: Hmmm, with your new answer the status goes back to 200 OK.  It must be either the IF Statement or the fact that I'm using RABL

Comment: In fact, RABL shouldn’t bring smth to redirection. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041838/how-to-remove-html-redirection-in-devise-authenticate-user) would help you?