# devise redirects instead of json response in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec, devise

I had overridden default responding in devise which renders json instead of html template. It works fine when I test it with curl or postman, but when it comes to test it with rspec. I have read infos how to test controllers with devise from readme.md, so that it works fine with logging into, but does not work when I want to test unauthenticated request.

Response received:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://test.host/users/sign_in\">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

instead of:

```
{"error":"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

app/controllers/playlists_controller.rb:

```
class PlaylistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    render json: Playlist.all
  end
end
```

app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  clear_respond_to
  respond_to :json
end
```

spec/controllers/playlists_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe PlaylistsController do
  context 'when user is not signed in' do
    it 'returns authorization error message' do
      get :index
      expect(response.body).to eq 'some message here'
    end
  end
end
```

spec/support/devise.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work in your controller test and does work in curl is because you aren't hitting the `:index` with format of `:json` (which you've written logic to `respond_to :json`).

Change this

```
it 'returns authorization error message' do
  get :index
  ...
end
```

to this

```
it 'returns authorization error message' do
  get :index, format: :json
  ...
end
```

Comment: That worked. I am wondering why this works for curl without setting Content-Type or Accept headers and for rspec not...

Comment: Interesting. I assumed you used content type json in curl. I actually don't know why it would use json without content type set

Comment: Actually no header was set. It should respond to json by default as it was supposed in overridden controller. Anyway - thanks for answering me :)

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5, the only way I could get the controller action to process as JSON was :

```
get :action, params: { format: :json, ... }
```

Hope this can help !

Answer (score 0):

You can define `FailureApp` or use conditional filters, both suggested in the answer to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10042104/580346

Comment: Fine, this is adding additional logic for tests. I already have this working with curl, but this is failing for tests. I don't think I should change app code only for tests.

Comment: You are right, I missed that it works with curl and fails in tests. Btw regarding the format and headers you may like this article: http://blog.iempire.ru/2016/09/05/rails-obstractions/